# Error when trying to DATEADD milliseconds in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters

So I have an enddate parameter in my report and I have the following code under Default Value to get me the last day of the previous month.

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1))
```

This works fine, returning `04-30-2016`. That's fine and dandy but when I go to use the Subscription piece in SSRS it has the datetime field as: `04-30-2016 12:00:00 AM`. So I tried doing the following to my code to have it shave off three milliseconds:

```
=DateAdd("ms", -3,DateAdd("d", 0, DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), 1)))
```

When I try to run my report I get the following error:

> The DefaultValue expression for the report parameter "enddate" contains an error: Argument 'Interval' is not a valid value. (rsRuntimeErrorInExpression)

How do I fix this error and get my report running as it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AddMilliseconds` function will work for you in this case.

```
=DateAdd("d",-1,DateSerial(Now.Year,Now.Month, 1)).AddMilliseconds(-3)
```

This gives you the last day of the previous month substracting three milliseconds.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks. I was actually looking for the 1st day of the current month minus the three milliseconds to get me end-of-month, so I just changed that first -1 to a 0 and it worked fine.